# Use Microsoft excel sheet feature in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007

In Microsoft Excel they have a sheets feature where I can make many sheets in one document.
That helps me a lot by keeping various related data in separate sheets but in one file.

I want a similar thing in Microsoft Word, where I can have various sheets or various data sheets but in single document.  Currently, I have to create different files for each different data.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Insert -> Table -> Excel Spreadsheet

[image]

Now you have the spreadsheet embedded in Word. You can add as many as you want. To edit double click it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document embed feature of Word . Word saves the child document inside the parent document.